# Doctrine MongoDB ODM search query

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-mongodb

I want to create a full text search with mongodb. How can I create the following query. With the query builder API?

```
db.Item.runCommand("text", {search: "Awesome"});
```

Is that possible? Or how can I execute a native query.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure text search is enabled for your mongodb

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-text-search/

The first step is to create an index in your document:

```
     use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

     /**
     * Class Item
     * @MongoDB\Document(repositoryClass="Acme\StoreBundle\ItemRepository")
     * @MongoDB\Indexes({
     *   @MongoDB\Index(keys={"title"="text"})
     * })
     */
    class Item
    {
        /**
         * @MongoDB\Id
         */
        protected $id;

        //...

     }
```

Then you can create the schema to ensure the index

```
php app/console doctrine:mongodb:schema:create
```

In your custom repository you can now query a command like this:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html#custom-repository-classes

```
public function findFullText($searchTerm, $limit = 10)
    {
        $resultSet = new ArrayCollection();

        //-- runCommand
        $itemResultSet = $this->getDocumentManager()->getDocumentDatabase('AcmeStoreBundle:Item')->command([
            'text' => 'Item',
            'search' => $searchTerm,
            'limit' => $limit
        ]);

        foreach ($itemResultSet['results'] as $itemResult) {
            $resultSet->add($this->uow->getOrCreateDocument('\Acme\StoreBundle\Document\Item', $itemResult['obj']));
        }

        return $resultSet;
    }
```

This is probaby not the most sophisticated way. But it will provide you with the desired set of documents.